# checkout hangs on Stencil theme

Tags: bigcommerce

We are in the process of developing a theme for a client using Stencil. On our local development the checkout.php just hangs. Cart loads fine but just sits there moving to the checkout. Should it be possible to complete checkout thru our local development? Are there special configurations that have to be made?

Comment: What version of node are you running?

Comment: I'm running version 5.6.0

Comment: just tried running it under v4.4.0 and am having the same issue

Comment: Try 4.2.6 or lower.

Comment: Thanks! That did it.